# Error "Module XYZ.dll failed to load" when using Regsvr32 to register a DLL on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dll

When I try to register a DLL file on Windows 7 (32-bit) using [Regsvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx), it gives the following error:

> The module "XYZ.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at
>   the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary
>   or dependent .DLL files

I don't have any issues on Windows XP or Windows Vista.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be missing a dll on which the one you're trying to register is dependent.

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check this.